# Programming a GUI based Markdown editor on my website

Tags: javascript, html, web, markdown

I already have the website set up, and I have the backend setup to handle the Markdown text submitted from a textarea, but I want to know how to implement a GUI editor.

This is a screenshot of the design.

[image]

Now, I have realized that what I want to do is similar to the formatting buttons here on Stackoverflow and on Reddit as well, but I still can't figure out how to do it...

My ultimate goal is to program the ability for the admin to press "B" and the text editor will either:

1. add ** ** with the curser between the pair of asterisks.
2. prepend ** and append ** to a section of highlighted text.

Anyway, I'm trying to figure this out and I don't know where to start. Advice?

Comment: I was experimenting with a similar thing a few months back. You can view my basic prototype here https://jsfiddle.net/www139/zzq5axtL/. This can be very dangerous because of the HTML tags implemented with possible JavaScript event handlers. Be sure to remove the tags when it gets to the server. You don't want to run JavaScript. My prototype doesn't actually use any text element at all! It just listens for key presses/key down to insert span elements with each character inside.

Comment: I'll take a look at this, thanks!

**Edit:** I took a look at it... I'm not really sure how this is even supposed to work.

Comment: Why can't you use editors like [ckeditor](http://ckeditor.com/demo)?

Comment: I tried to use ckeditor, and I couldn't seem to get it to work with my current system. I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

While ckeditor is a WYSIWYG-Editor, I assume you wanted a [WYSIWYM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYM) Editor.

[lepture/editor](https://github.com/lepture/editor) ([demo](http://lab.lepture.com/editor/)) offers shortcuts (like your Ctrl + B) and shows the markup, but additionally as formated text.

Alternatively use [hallojs.org markdown](http://hallojs.org/demo/markdown/) and use HTML5 editing with buttons or plain Markdown.

Comment: 1. You were correct. I was looking for a WYSIWYM Editor. In the end I just wrote my own, it took a few hours of watching tutorial videos for JavaScript, but I managed to get it done.

2. Now that I have my WYSIWYM editor created, I'm working on moving the textarea to one side and having a live preview on the right side of the textarea. The option would exist to hide the live preview if one wished. Still working on that part. 

3. I appreciate the comment, regardless! Thanks!

Comment: hey, @klml, can you please tell how to integrate WYSIWYM editor on our websites, or is there any integration guide?
lepture/editor. I want it to integrate on reactjs website , i think it is not fit for reactjs till now

Comment: @RohanDevaki currently I prefer installing [SimpleMDE](https://github.com/sparksuite/simplemde-markdown-editor#install).
I am not familiar with reactjs, so I cant help you integrating simplemd. But you only need add js and css to your frontend.